# How can I access my database (mongodb mlab) directly from a react application without actually having to build an api?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs

There are tons of examples creating a react crud application using api, but I could not find one that directly access the database. Even when I continued with the api, I didn't know how to restrict people from using the api to delete and put data stored. Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out firebase. Here's a tutorial on integrating with React:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwNATxfUsgI

Firebase is a backend as a service. It won't let you access your mongo db database, but it will allow you to provide you with a databse